# Can I convert a statistical significance into a zscore using a normal distribution?

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution

Suppose I want to turn statistical significance of 0.05 into a z-score of ~1.64

Can I use a normal distribution to convert these?

Comment: This sounds like an odd thing to do... can you give more details about the circumstances that lead you to try to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the quantile function of the Normal distribution:

```
R> qnorm(c(0.05, 0.95))
[1] -1.64485  1.64485
R>
```

And if you're wondering, the probability distribution function does the inverse:

```
R> pnorm( qnorm(c(0.05, 0.95)) )
[1] 0.05 0.95
R>
```

Any decent numerical / statistical library or language will have these; I use R for convenience. Eg for C++ you have [Boost Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/normal_dist.html).

Comment: Thanks Dirik, can you explain how the distribution is a convertor for significance into a z-score.

Comment: It's a bit of a tautology: the z-score $Z$ is the value such that the quantile is $\alpha$, here 0.05 (or $\alpha/2$ if you consider both tails). In that sense 1.64 corresponds to a 10% critical value ("z-score") with 5% in each tail.  For 5% in both you need 1.96 corresponding to the two-sided 2.5% tails.